Axios Incorrectly Deserializes Into Response Schema Containing Maps
When I make a GET request with Axios and explicitly provide a schema for the response type containing Maps, the Maps are not deserialized into Map instances.
I have an API that returns a hardcoded response that looks like:
{
    "key1": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2"
    },
    "key2": {
        "key3": "val3",
        "key4": "val4"
    }
}

My code to send the request look like:
interface Schema {
  key1: Map<string, Map<string, string>>;
  key2: Map<string, Map<string, string>>;
}

function App() {
  axios.get<Schema>('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log(response.data.key1.entries())
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    });

  return (<div></div>);
}

export default App;

Although the console.log(response.data) statement outputs a seemingly correctly structured Schema:

The console.log(response.data.key1.entries()) yields the following error:
response.data.key1.entries is not a function
TypeError: response.data.key1.entries is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31:36

Looking closer at the output of the first log statement, it appears as though the inner maps in the response are not being deserialized as Map instances, but instead plain Objects.
How can I ensure that the type of key1 and key2 are of type Map so that I am able to iterate over its entries?

Have you tried Record<string, Record<string, string>> instead of Map<string, Map<string, string>> ?

@RoarS. I suppose I could, but then I can't use the nice properties/methods of the Map.

Then I believe you'll have to write a function that converts key1 and key2 in the response to Map. BR
